# Angularjs how to change text in a view from a different view's controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-view

I am missing something very elementary....

I have three views created in angularJS: a header, a body and a footer. I want to change the text in the header from login to logout upon successful login, also from logout to login when the user is logged out.

My files/code:

index.php:

```
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

header.page.html ( I think I want ng-bind or {{some var}} here )

```
    <li><a href="#login" >Login</a></li>
```

login.component.js  (not sure how to get a value to the header.page.html)

```
    login(){
        var user = {
            company: this.company,
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        };
        var me = this;
        this.$auth
            .login(user)
            .then(function (response) {
                me.$auth.setToken(response.data);


// CHANGE LOGIN TO LOGOUT IN HEADER



                me.$state.go('app.dashboard');
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log("error response", response);
            })
    };
```

And the logout function (Not sure how to get a value to header.page.html)

```
function dashboardController($state, $scope, $auth){
$scope.isAuthenticated = function () {
    return $auth.isAuthenticated();
};
document.title = "Dashboard";
$scope.logout = function () {
    $auth.logout();

    //change Logout To Login text in header

    $state.go('app.home');
};
```

}

Comment: Inject `$rootScope` to your controller, and bind the value to it

Comment: You can broadcast  a user login/logout message. I'm not sure if it's the best option, but it will work.

Comment: Alon Eitan I guess I was hoping to avoid $rootScope but your comment has helped my search....currently now reading a page on why to not use rootScope but hey I just want it to work.... that said would have been done 24 hours ago with jquery

Comment: Vladimir Furso I am guessing a login logout broadcast would be a useful thing to have.... For example I would want to log the user out of all open tabs. Still don't think I would be sure how to get the value over to header.page.html

Comment: I agree, using `$rootScope` is not a good practice, but @VladimirFurso solution is a great workaround (Tutorial https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Comment: in the routing section you can make arrangements to check if user is authenticated or not and based on that you can call specific controller - function. Make a google search for it.

Comment: In the view, use something like `<div ng-if="isAuthenticated()">You're logged in</div><div ng-if="!isAuthenticated()">You're not logged in</div>`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use $broadcast, $emit and $on. More details in: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Other solution would be using $rootScope, but take care about poluting it.

As far as it regards to some application related information, like user information, honestly, a solution based on $rootScope is not totally wrong.

You should definately avoid $rootScope for feature specific information.

I would study more about using broadcast in order to decide.

Comment: Ironically it looks like I need to broadcast on rootScope as there is no parent-child relationship. The login is a child component on the main view, but the main view has no relationship to the header. Is that your understanding as well?

Comment: The $broadcast is always made from $rootScope down to the $scope object. But consider the fact that the usage of $rootScope is not actually a bad choice if the information regards to the entire application. Sometimes is much easier to use $rootScope to store, for instance, the user's privileges, and access it directly throughout the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only change text in header form login you can get access to your

```
<li><a id="login" href="#login" >Login</a></li>
```

like this: `document.getElementById("login")` and set new text or you can use service. Service you should inejct to login and header controller.

Comment: In getting to know angularjs a bit more I feel like the correct solution is to broadcast the login event, therefore the view becomes separated from an alternate controller. Changing the view from another controller, which is what I used to do with Jquery, ends up real messy.